# Java merge sort

Tags: java, sorting, merge

This is the merge sort algorithm provided by the java book im using, but the code doesnt work. It returns an array with some numbers duplicated that werent in the original number list. Any ideas why this code isnt working, thanks? Edit: The output of running this is: "
7
2
12
4
2
      So it duplicates the 2's
2
2
2
4
12

```
public class Nothing1{

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        comp<Integer> c = new comp<Integer>();

        Integer[] values1 = new Integer[5];

        values1[0] = 7;
        values1[1] = 2;
        values1[2] = 12;
        values1[3] = 4;
        values1[4] = 2;

        for(int index= 0; index <= values1.length-1; ++index)
            {
                System.out.println(values1[index]);
            }

        c.mergeSort(values1);

        for(int index= 0; index <= values1.length-1; ++index)
            {
                System.out.println(values1[index]);
            }



    }

     public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] data)
        {
            mergeSort(data, 0, data.length-1);
        }

        private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] data, int min, int max)
        {
            if(min < max)
            {
                int mid = (min + max)/2;
                mergeSort(data, min, mid);
                mergeSort(data, mid+1, max);
                merge(data, min, mid, max);
            }
        }

        private static <T extends Comparable <T>> 
                void merge(T[] data, int first, int mid, int last)
        {
            T[] temp = (T[])(new Comparable[data.length]);

            int first1 = first, last1=mid;
            int first2 = mid+1, last2=last;
            int index = first1;

            while(first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2)
            {
                if(data[first1].compareTo(data[first2]) < 0)
                {
                    temp[index] = data[first];
                    first1++;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[index] = data[first2];
                    first2++;
                }
                index++;
            }

            while(first1 <= last1)
            {
                temp[index] = data[first1];
                first1++;
                index++;
            }

            while(first2 <= last2)
            {
                temp[index] = data[first2];
                first2++;
                index++;
            }

            for(index = first; index <=last; index++)
                data[index] = temp[index];
        }
}
```

Comment: Why is the code at the bottom commented out?

Comment: And where is the calling code?

Comment: @sager89  I dont think its used by merge sort, its used by the other sorting algorithms that are above it

Comment: @Keppil I have put it in now

Comment: `temp[index] = data[first];` should be `temp[index] = data[first1];` (first while loop), right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to change one of variables, arent you?

Imagine you have 4 and 3 in the current to merge array.

Your first1 and last1 is 0
Your first2 and last2 is 1

When you compare it, you enter to the else and copy the 3 to the first position of index, that is right. And then you move first2 one above.

But what about the 4?? You should copy it after the 3, right? Just in the second position of the index.

Maybe Im wrong.

Im sorry, my english is bad.

Answer (score 0):

The error basically comes down to a typo in your `merge` function:

```
private static <T extends Comparable <T>> 
        void merge(T[] data, int first, int mid, int last)
{
    T[] temp = (T[])(new Comparable[data.length]);

    int first1 = first, last1=mid;
    int first2 = mid+1, last2=last;
    int index = first1;

    while(first1 <= last1 && first2 <= last2)
    {
        if(data[first1].compareTo(data[first2]) < 0)
        {
            // the next line has to use indices that can change during this loop
            temp[index] = data[first1]; // change in this line first->first1
            first1++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[index] = data[first2];
            first2++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    //...
```

With the wrong code your array goes through the following conditions:

```
7 2 12 4  2 (initial state; merge indices 0;1 next)
2 7 12 4  2 (still correct; merge indices 0-1;2 next)
2 2 12 4  2 (error here)
2 2 12 2  4
2 2  2 4 12
```

In the erroneous merge step the following happens:

1. copy from index 0 to index 0
2. copy from index 0 to index 1 (error here: should be copied from index 1)
3. copy from index 2 to index 2

the error happens, because the data is read from index `first`, but index `first1` is changed

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    static void merge(ArrayList < Integer > orig, ArrayList < Integer > left, ArrayList < Integer > right) {
        ArrayList < Integer > temp = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        int ls = left.size();
        int rs = right.size();
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < ls && j < rs) {
            if (left.get(i) <= right.get(j)) {
                orig.set(k, left.get(i));
                i++;
            } else {
                orig.set(k, right.get(j));
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        int tempind = 0;
        if (i >= ls) {
            temp = right;
            tempind = j;
        } else {
            temp = left;
            tempind = i;
        }

        for (int n = tempind; n < temp.size(); n++) {
            orig.set(k, temp.get(n));
            k++;
        }
    }
    static void merge_sort(ArrayList < Integer > list) {
        int len = list.size();
        if (len < 2) {
            return;
        }
        ArrayList < Integer > leftHalf = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        ArrayList < Integer > rightHalf = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        int mid = len / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            leftHalf.add(list.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = mid; i < len; i++) {
            rightHalf.add(list.get(i));
        }
        merge_sort(leftHalf);
        merge_sort(rightHalf);
        merge(list, leftHalf, rightHalf);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        ArrayList < Integer > x = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        int[] arr = {
            9,
            8,
            4,
            5,
            2,
            7,
            1,
            3,
            0,
            2
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            x.add(arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(x);
        merge_sort(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```